# Why is fdisk not returning anything inside LXD container

Tags: linux, lxc, container

I am little confused , i have a lxc container and if i do `lsusb` inside the conatiner i get the following output

```
root@blunt01:/dev/bus/usb/002# lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0424:2512 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0424:2512 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 8564:1000 Transcend Information, Inc. JetFlash
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0529:0001 Aladdin Knowledge Systems HASP copy protection dongle
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0624:0249 Avocent Corp. Virtual Keyboard/Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0624:0248 Avocent Corp. Virtual Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Also the `lsblk` shows me the following :

```
root@blunt01:/dev/bus/usb/002# lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 278.9G  0 disk 
|-sda1   8:1    0 230.9G  0 part /
|-sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
`-sda5   8:5    0    48G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0   5.5T  0 disk 
sdc      8:32   0   5.5T  0 disk 
sde      8:64   1  14.7G  0 disk 
`-sde1   8:65   1  14.7G  0 part
```

But the problem is this :

1. The `fdisk -l` shows me NOTHING at all
2. I need to mount the USB listed at BUS 002 , Device 007 . How can i do so ?

Comment: May be those nodes are missing. If so then create those links by using `mknod` command

Comment: @SHW so you mean i don't have anything in my /dev/ ? can u please elaborate how to do so]

Comment: grep -E d[a-g] /proc/partitions > list
for i in `seq \`sed -n '$=' list\``
do
 mknod /dev/`sed -n ${i}p list | awk '{print $4}'` b 8 `sed -n ${i}p list | awk '{print $2}'` > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
done

Comment: how do i make use of it ? Also what does this do ?

Answer (score 0):

**Pseudo answer**

Since, in comment I can't write code. Hence commenting here in answer:

**Unable to post here the bash code. Better you copy-paste above code which I had replied to you in your question**

Above code will create the nodes for all the partitions available in system (recognized by /proc/partition)

Comment: this is bash script, right ?

Comment: it says 

`mknod: invalid option -- 'n'` 
awk: fatal: cannot open file `b' for reading (No such file or directory)